# What is the default value for Empty Temporary Internet Files when browser is closed in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cache, browser-cache

We have four different machines that all have "*Empty Temporary Internet Files when browser is closed*" set to true (checked) in IE8's Internet Options (located under the *Security* section in the *Advanced* tab). No one remembers checking that checkbox to turn on the setting. What is the default value supposed to be? I'm specifically interested in Windows 7 and Windows XP.

I have run *rsop.msc* on one of the corporate machines—3 of the 4 are members of a corporate network/domain—and see this under User Configuration, which makes the current scenario seem even stranger:

[image: Resultant Set of Policy - for the user]

The Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) also shows the *Configure Delete Browsing History on exit* setting to be *Not configured* (under Computer Configuration>>Administrative Templates>>Windows Components>>Internet Explorer>>Delete Browsing History).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default for "Empty Temporary Internet Files when browser is closed" is disabled (not check-marked).

Most likely somebody turned it on as they probably wanted to cover their tracks for some reason, so they're also probably not going to admit they did it. :)

Comment: I turn it on because that is where malware loves to hide.

Comment: do you know of anywhere that this default is documented?